# Record Settings in Xcode: Swift 2.0

Tags: xcode, audio, swift2, avaudioplayer

Here is a piece of **Swift 2.0** code that I saw in a tutorial (https://youtu.be/4qj1piMAPE0). I get the error on the first line:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more content.

```
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
...
var recordSettings = [AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey: 320000,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
var recordSettings : [String : Any] =
[
    AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue,
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
    AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0
]
```